# CSS Grid Alignment

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to make my website responsive but I have a little problem with my css grid.

I'm not getting how to align the cards also to the right border of the top image.

So, the first column is in the right position, but the other two should be more on the right.

[image]

html:

```
    <!-- info -->
        <div class="info">
            <div class="images">
               <div class="images-show"> 
                <img src="img/show1.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="img/show2.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="img/show3.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="img/show4.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="img/show5.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="img/show6.jpg" alt="">
               </div>
            </div>  
            <div class="contacts">
                <h3>The Great Northern</h3>
                <p>15 Mulholland Drive, Twin Peaks</p>
                <p>+41 151515</p>
                <p>greatnorthern@hotel.com</p>
            <div class="form">
                <form id="form" class="contact-form" method="post">
                    <input type="text" class="contact-form-text" placeholder="Your name">
                    <input type="email" class="contact-form-text" placeholder="Your email">
                    <input type="text" class="contact-form-text" placeholder="Your phone number">
                    <textarea class="contact-form-text" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" class="contact-form-btn" value="Send">
                </form>
            </div>
            </div> 
            </div>
```

css:

```
.info {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}


.images {
    margin-top: 20px; 
    grid-gap: 10px;
    width: 50%;
}

.images-show {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 10px;
}

.images img{
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
}

@media(max-width: 900px) {
    .info {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
    .images {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: would you be able to post the relevant html and css?

Comment: you're right.. done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main issue is that your images are direct children of the grid container and they have a fixed width of 200px. This way, no matter what you do, they can't occupy the whole space.

At this moment, the best you can do is probably add the justify-items to the grid container, like this:

```
.images-show {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  justify-items: center;
}
```

Now they won't align perfectly, but they are nicely centered.

What I would do, though, is wrap every individual image inside their own div (even better a `<figure>` tag). Then you have more possibility to size and style the images.

Comment: with "justify-items: center" the alignment is not bad and it for sure makes more sense than before.. I will also try to follow to other suggestion.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try for wrapper

```
display: flex; 
justify-content: space-between;
```